# Which type of paint for a surface with slight imperfections?

Tags: bathroom, doors, painting, repainting

[image: Bathroom door]

Hi guys I'm planning on repainting my door its plan but it's slightly textured from previous paint I was wondering whether I would need to use a primer on this door and which type of paint ?
As I've been searching around the consensus is not to use oil based paint any suggestions much welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use oil-based paint. More expensive and harder to clean up. I'd use acrylic latex (water-based) paint.  No primer is required. Make sure the door is clean, (I.e.: no oil, grease, crayon marks, etc.). Quick drying and easy clean up.

Comment: Oh, and make sure the existing paint is not oil-based. Test it...there are lots of test kits that can do the trick.

Comment: Oh, the ""sheen" will have as much to do with noticing imperfections as anything. The higher the gloss finish, the more likely you'll see the imperfections. "Color" has nothing to do with hiding the imperfections...